# Is there a way to loop through a list with a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

Basically I am trying scrape all HTML tags from a list of HTML files. 
When I am trying to do this I am getting the error:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.

So is there a way to iterate over a list with regex?

Here is the code I am using:

```py
import pymssql
import re

conn = pymssql.connect(
    host='xxx',
    port=xxx,
    user='xxx',
    password='xxx',
    database='xxxx'
)
cursor = conn.cursor() 
cursor.execute('SELECT 'column' FROM 'table'')

text = cursor.fetchall()

conn.close()

raw = []  
raw.append(text)

str(raw)

x = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', raw)
```

Comment: So you want to remove some text from each item in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.

refers to the fact that `raw` points to a `list` object, to point it to a string. You need to do:

```
raw = str(raw)  # instead of just str(raw)
```

but, if `text` is indeed a string why not just:

```
x = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', text)
```

For more details see the documentation on [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str), the quote below is from there:

> Return a str version of object. See str() for details.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) package. It's an HTML parser which you can treat like a normal python dictionary.

Comment: Just used BeautifulSoup for this, much better!